# How do I left align the one table and right align the other table that uses the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Initially, I can't change the class name for instance:

```
<table class="firsttable"> This is the firstable that must be left align
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>

<table class="firsttable"> And this is the second table that must be center align
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
```

How do I code it in css?

Comment: have you tried the selector + or ~ to update CSS of second table ? such as `.firsttable +.firsttable {text-alig:center}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align two inline-blocks left and right on same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272605/align-two-inline-blocks-left-and-right-on-same-line)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below CSS, It works as intended

```
<style>
.firsttable:nth-child(1) { text-align:left; }
.firsttable:nth-child(2) { text-align:right; }
</style>
```

It's CSS3 though.

Answer (score 0):

First table CSS selector:

```
.firsttable:first-of-type
```

If second table is last:

```
.firsttable:last-of-type
```

Otherwise, second table CSS selector is this:

```
.firsttable:nth-of-type(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ids:

HTML:

```
<table class="firsttable" id="table1">
...
</table>
<table class="firsttable" id="table2">
...
```

CSS:

```
#table1 {
    text-align:left;
}
#table2 {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Does this work?

Answer (score -1):

In this case it is better or from my sense I always make it by adding an inline style in the table and I think their no need to create any other style for it in CSS.

***`<table class="firsttable" style="text-align:left"> This is the firstable that must be left align`***

And the second table may be another inline style of text-align:center

***`<table class="firsttable" style="text-align:center"> And this is the second table that must be center align`***

It is the best approach. But you can also can create some different id here or

```
 .firsttable:nth-child(1) { text-align:left; }
 .firsttable:nth-child(2) { text-align:center; }
```

Problem in this is if you use it then if another table appear in this web page area than it will arise a problem. So it is better to use inline style in this case.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to move the table to the left and one to the right add the following to the appropreate table.

For the align right. Add this at the opening tag `<table>`.

`style="float:right;"`

For the algin left add the same code to the exactly same place but change the "left" to "right" depending on where you want it to be.

To aling text do as the other people have seggested.

J. Carter :)