# How do I align Font Awesome icons to the right?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying `text-align: right` in my CSS, but text-align is not moving it for some reason. I want the website title left aligned and the icon right aligned on the same line. Here's what I am trying.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t39rk01d/)

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="top-container">
    <h2>Website Title</h2>

    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.top-container {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.top-container i {
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

.top-container h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align two inline-blocks left and right on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272605/align-two-inline-blocks-left-and-right-on-same-line)

Comment: Try to put in `<div class="top-container" style="
    text-align: right;>`

Comment: Just add float:right to the i element

Comment: As a side-note, you're going to have _other issues_ once you add the navigation that presumably goes along with the three bar icon... :)

Answer (score 8):

`text-align` will align the text *within*  the element which you are assigning it to, which doesn't do anything in an `inline-block` element like this (since that's just as wide as its contents). Use `float: right;` instead of `text-align: right`

https://jsfiddle.net/s4a9sct9/1/

Answer (score 4):

If `text-align: right` is not working, try `float: right`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #eaeaea;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
}

.top-container.float-style>h2 {
  display: inline;
}

.top-container.float-style>i {
  float: right;
  line-height:26px; 
}
.top-container.absolute-style > i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="top-container float-style">
  <h2>Website Title float style</h2>
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</div>

<hr style="margin:30px 0px;">
<div class="top-container absolute-style">
  <h2>Website Title absolute</h2>
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom Id to the element --> `<i class="fal fa-phone" id="customfa"></i>`
Head to your CSS file and right these -->

#customfa{right: 10%;}
You can use right, left , top and bottom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Can use either pull-right or align-right or float-right

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-2x pull-left"></i> Font Awesome<br>Version 4.7.0</a>

    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-align-right" title="Align Right"></i>
      </a>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The display must be changed for text-align to apply

```
  .myClass {
      display: block;
      text-align: right;
    }
```